# Run a macro by button when a cell is selected in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to assign a macro to a button, but the code run in that condition when any cell is selected in a Range of `ActiveSheet("A:A")`. Otherwise it prompt me a msg box "cell is not selected".

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: I need just a macro code in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
    ' Do your stuff
Else
    MsgBox "No cell is selected"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is also works for me:

```
Sub PrintPreview()
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cell is selected"
    Else
        'write code here
    End If
End Sub
```